# Speed up video x1.5 but keep all frames

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

So I'm trying to speed up all my tv episodes (because some of them are really slow paced). The source is 30fps. And if already tried to do this with the following command:(I'm doing x1.6 because that's easier to make the setpts value (otherwise it would be 0.66666666666...)

```
ffmpeg -i VideoOriginal.mkv -r 48 -filter:v "setpts=0.625*PTS" VideoSpeedup.mkv
```

But the filesize here is WAY lower (maybe I should also use a preset for the quality?)
Either way. The file is 40 minutes long and pretty much is broken after 10 minutes (VLC starts to misinterpreted timestamps and the player is pretty much F*cked).

Also the audio isn't speedup with this method.

Any tips on how to make this better?

(Reason why I want to 'keep all frames'. Is because since I'm going x1.6 I can just do 48fps meaning that I don't actually lose or have to generate new frames.)

EDIT: just realised that my original file's fps is 23.97612 .... I guess that does make things more complicated...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When changing the video speed, you usually do not have to set `-r`, but just let ffmpeg change the timestamps of the frames. This might lead to frame drops, which can of course be avoided by setting the proper framerate as you tried, but you have to set it *after* the input specification.

To speed up both video and audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.625*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.6[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Audio tempo is the inverse of the factor modifying frame timestamps. And with the framerate change:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.625*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.6[a]" -r 48 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

If your video does not have audio, you can remove the audio filter from `filter_complex`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.625*PTS[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

> But the filesize here is WAY lower

That's because everything is re-encoded. Usually, `libx264` is used for video encoding. The default quality should be good, but you can change it by using the `-crf` option, for example. See the [H.264 encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more.

You could also just tell VLC to speed up playback from the *Playback* menu. This avoids unnecessary conversion and hardcoding of the speed change.

Comment: Thanks! Trying it out right now. Just wanted to say that with my previous command I was getting ' Starting new cluster due to timestamp'. But now with your command I'm getting 'Past duration 0.994987 too large' pretty frequently... Is that something I should worry about, or just ignore?

Comment: I tried it out and seems like it converted it to a 23.97612 file instead of a 48fps file which makes everything look very choppy now. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Making it 48fps is not automatically going to make it any smoother. Can you post the entire command-line log?

Comment: It will right? Because right now it's cramming 48frames into 23,.... which results in more choppy video. Here's my log: https://pastebin.com/LAqctUK7

Comment: Hm, you can try with `-r 48` to avoid dropping frames, but it still should not look choppy. Perhaps try with a newer version of ffmpeg? Yours is from 2015. http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Didn't even realise that I was on old version (nice spotting!)
I updated to the newest stable version. Your original suggestion still gives me something that looks equally choppy. But If I add the -r 48 after my input (like on my original command) then the results is PERFECT! Exactly what I was looking for. (Maybe EDIT the answer to include the '-r 48' and I'll mark is as the answer! (thank you so much btw!)

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know! Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

(Because you mentioned VLC in your question ...)

In VLC, go to the `Playback` menu, select `Speed/Faster` or `Speed/Faster (fine)`.

<sub>Edit: and @slhck agrees, so I must be right   :-)</sub>

Comment: Yeah I know VLC has that built in. But I'm converting them so I can put them in Plex and stream them to my ipad/smartphone. But thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this batch file:

```
rem Based on your findings i found the following for making screen recordings.
rem First set your devices and get https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free/releases
rem To list your devices: (Remove rem...)
rem ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
rem ffmpeg  -f dshow  -list_options true -i video="screen-capture-recorder"
goto :end rem (remove rem...)
rem recording the screen with my audio out device: (Use no codec for compression, long file) (Also: match ffmpeg codecs agains own video card if not nvenc compat.)
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 256M -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="Stereo-mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 10M -bufsize 20M -qp 0 output.mp4
rem Remove double frames (audio stays ok though)
ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 10M -bufsize 20M -qp 0 output_decimated.mp4
rem get the audio out and speed it up, my case times 2
ffmpeg -y -i output_decimated.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=(1/0.50)[a]" -map "[a]" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output_fast.mp3
rem Add some volume, because the mixed music is loud. Other way around i made the mixed music less loud with:
rem ffmpeg -y -i 2018.mp3 -filter:a "volume=0.20" 2018_soft.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i output_fast.mp3 -filter:a "volume=6.0" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output_fast_hard.mp3
rem Mix sped up audio only from decimated video with music
ffmpeg -y -i output_fast_hard.mp3 -i 2018_soft.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest" output_mixed.mp3
rem Mix the (mixed) sound back to the 30 fps video. Now the sound will go twice as much to fast, but: (see next)
ffmpeg -y -i output_decimated.mp4 -i output_mixed.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output_30.mp4
rem Speed up the video twice, but KEEP ALL (decimated) FRAMES! Sound stays same, so it should match the sped up video AND previous sped audio.
ffmpeg -y -i output_30.mp4 -vf settb=\(1/60\),setpts=N/TB/60 -r 60 -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10M -bufsize 20M -bf:v 3 -preset slow -rc:v vbr_hq -rc-lookahead 32 output_60.mp4
```

:end
pause

If I'm all correct, I tested it, the result looks nice, smooth video, but: you should make slow movement while recording.... that's the bug of this. Real time video games can not slowed down, or need to be patched somehow, no internal movement / time fix are in games present, unless build in recording, like gta5 has

Maybe you see some for improvement of screen recording. Like why it is not possible to record 60 fps? Is there a way ffmpeg stores superfast in real time memory, like if i have 32 or 64 gigs of ram?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n76nhnMR6Tc&list=PLetXkEBOuSmaP0O9firbuT9lHcn25QuiW